# How can I evaluate data mining model?

Tags: data-mining, regression, decision-trees

I will evaluate classification models I made. That's logistic regression and decision tress.

1. What I use standards for comparison?
2. Suppose model selection's standard is ASE. One is high ASE of training data, low ASE of test data, and the other is ASE of training data is low and ASE of test data is high.. If you select a model, which models do you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Accuracy (for classification problems)
- Precision
- Recall
- F1 Score
- AUC-ROC, particularly for imbalanced datasets

Good performance on the training set and bad performance on the test set is due to overfitting. So you should try to find ways to tackle overfitting, such as regularization of parameters, parameter tuning using cross-validation etc...

Answer (score 0):

The standards for evaluation of classification accuracy are:

1. F-score (usually [F1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) score, giving same importance to precision and recall)
2. AUC - [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) for binary classification (check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it))

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is not any standards and it completely depends on your case.

If the subject of your problem can be ignored some other characteristics such as balance/imbalance and binary/multi-class can narrow your search results.

Besides, there are many benchmarks which evaluate the classification results according to many parameters such as data-set population, class-based accuracy, overall accuracy to name but a few. Some of these benchmarks are **Landis-Koch Benchmark**, **Fleiss’ Benchmark**, **Altman’s Benchmark**, **Cicchetti’s Benchmark**.

Disclaimer:

If you use python I suggest you to use **[PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm)** which recommends the most fit metrics for evaluation and comparison. Here is a simple code to get the recommended parameters from this module:

```
>>> from pycm import *

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(matrix={"Class1": {"Class1": 1, "Class2":2}, "Class2": {"Class1": 0, "Class2": 5}})  

>>> print(cm.recommended_list)
["Kappa", "SOA1(Landis & Koch)", "SOA2(Fleiss)", "SOA3(Altman)", "SOA4(Cicchetti)", "CEN", "MCEN", "MCC", "J", "Overall J", "Overall MCC", "Overall CEN", "Overall MCEN", "AUC", "AUCI", "G", "DP", "DPI", "GI"]

>>> score = cm.Kappa
```